# Constant charge in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, electricity

We had special relativity introduced in our course and used it to derive some facts. At one place we used the fact that if in frame of reference $U$ the electron has charge $e$, then it also has charge $e$ in **any** frame of reference.

The justification of this fact was done more by waving the hands, though: *if the charge did transform from a frame of reference to another, it would be a disaster, because there'd be no state of equilibrium*

Can the fact that the electric charge doesn't depend on the frame of reference be justified in a little more rigorous manner?

Comment: @brucesmitherson That's charge **conservation** that comes from the vanishing four divergence, not charge **invariance**. And the latter is a separate postulate. It comes for instance by saying that you can take a number density and scale it by $e$ in your unit system to get a charge density. And answering in comments makes it so we I can't downvote an incorrect answer-comment.

Comment: @Timaeus you are correct, I commented without thinking too much (as often)

Comment: It can be justified. Basically, your course is doing it backwards, starting from E&M and adding in special relativity; if you do it this way, you've got to put in extra ad hoc assumptions. The fundamental way starts with "the QED Lagrangian is Lorentz invariant" and derives charge invariance from that.

Comment: Still, the approach your course is taking, bootstrapping itself up to a deeper theory by intuitive guesses, isn't illegitimate. It's really what physics is all about!

Comment: My course starts with special relativity and, just as a digression, derives a couple of things from electricity & magnetism. So I don't know what a Maxwell equation is (yet).

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the charge of an electron from *a static measurement in one frame.*

Another frame could determine the charge of an electron from *a static measurement in **their** frame.*

And they might agree or disagree. We postulate they agree, but we had three options:

- We could postulate that whether or not something is an electron depends on your frame (this would not be 100% totally out of line, for instance in quantum field theory in curved spacetime whether something is a vacuum does depend on whether two frames accelerate relative towards each other, and it predicts that a Geiger counter that clicks in one frame might not click if it accelerates and vice versa).
- We could postulate that the charge of an electron is not a fundamental universal constant. This basically makes charge not a property of the electron but instead a property of how things interact. Again, in QED this might seem less weird when you consider running constants and the differences between bare and dressed electrons.
- We could postulate that the charge and identity are the same in two frames. Effectively this means that instead of charge you can just count the number of positrons and such and then subtract the number of electrons and such and then you basically have the charge and really just multiply by $e$ to change unit systems from a natural system where the fundamental charge is one to another unit system where the fundamental charge isn't one.

Whether charge is conserved is a separate issue (that depends on a continuity equation, which comes from Maxwell). This is about the constant $e$ the charge per electron/positron. And the fact that we call it a constant and the fact that we don't expect something to stop being an electron in a different frame means we expect that third option.

The constant $e$ is just a unit conversion telling you the charge of an electron/positron relative to the unit of charge in your unit system. And like most systems of units it doesn't depend on your frame.

---

To be clear since people seem confused. We postulate that whether you have some number of electrons or positrons or muons and such is Lorentz invariant. This postulate is separate from Maxwell. Then we postulate that there is Lorentz scalar $q_i$ for each species type (one that depends on your system of units). Then we postulate that the charge four current $J$ is related to the number currents $n_e,$ $n_\mu,$ $n_\tau$ etcetera through the charges via $J=q_en_e+q_\mu n_\mu+\dots+ q_\tau n_\tau.$

And none of those subscripts are related to four vectors you could have $J^a=\sum_{\text{species}_i}q_in^a_i.$

---

> But I still don't understand why a moving electron couldn't have a different charge, thus react differently with our "static" electrons in our frame of reference.

Moving charges do interact differently than stationary charges. But the whole point of charge is to say that a moving or stationary electron exchanges momentum exactly negatively to the way an identically moving positron does. And we use the word charge to express this fact and we express it by saying they have exactly opposite charge.

And then we express the fact that a moving or stationary proton exchanges momentum exactly the way an identically moving positron does. And we use the word charge to express this fact and we express it by saying they have exactly identical charge.

And so on. For quarks you can say a moving or stationary up quark exchanges momentum exactly 1/3 the way an identically moving positron does. And we use the word charge to express this fact and we express it by saying the up quark has exactly 1/3 the charge.

It's these **differences** between particles with **different** charge that is physically meaningful and needs to be expressed. Maxwell explains how the motion of the charges affects what it does to other charges and what it feels from other charges. But it does so in a way where you can express having the opposite effect or having 1/3 the effect and we need the concept of **charge** to express the **difference** *between* **different** particle **species**.

You want to say things like two electrons both at rest a certain distance $d$ away feel forces **away** from each other exactly as strong as an electron and a positron both at rest a the same distance $d$ away feel forces **towards** each other exactly as strong as the two electrons did. And by using a *signed* charge you can express this like $\vec F_{ab}=kq_aq_b(\vec a-\vec b)/|\vec a-\vec b|^3$ and then just say that positrons and electrons have opposite charges.

You are trying to describe the differences between **species** when you talk about charge. So if you want species to be Lorentz invariant and you want to talk about the **different properties** of two species then you need Lorentz invariant properties to talk about the differences **between** the species.

Comment: "And the fact that we call it a constant and the fact that we don't expect something to stop being an electron in a different frame means we expect that third option" I cannot follow the logic here. (-1)

Comment: @brucesmitherson We **postulate** that $e$ is a frame independent constant. If we didn't do that then we would have to adjust our language and not call it a constant. Or we would have to adjust our language to not use the word electron as if it were a frame independent label. It's just a summary of what was said earlier.

Comment: I could take the minus one if you edit you answer, just one character, the vote is locked (I apologize, I am a little impulsive sometimes, and you did not deserve a -1)

Comment: I don't see how charge conservation is a separate statement. If $j^\mu$ is conserved, you can prove that $\int d^3x j^0$ is a Lorentz scalar, hence charge is invariant.

Comment: @KevinZhou Charge conservation comes from the continuity equation. And nothing about that has the word electron. It doesn't tell you that two people agree on how many electrons there are, or whether what one person calls an electron would be called an electron by the other person. Because the continuity equation doesn't have the word electron in it. So it doesn't tell you what $e$ is. The continuity equation is about the four current and doesn't mention how (if at all) that is related to number density of electrons (which is what $e$ postulates) ...

Comment: @KevinZhou and charge conservation does **not** tell you that number density of electrons is a Lorentz scalar. Which was my whole point. We postulate that number density for each species type is conserved and that four current is **equal** to a specific linear combination of the number four current of each species and the numerical values of that linear combination are $\pm e$ (whose value depends on your system of units) and this is a separate postulate from Maxwell and can't be derived from Maxwell alone since that is only about charges and fields and not about species number density.

Comment: Okay, we're talking about different things: I am talking about starting from the QED Lagrangian, from which you can derive that $\psi^\dagger \psi$ is number density and $e \psi^\dagger \psi$ is charge density, and both are scalars. I think you're talking about starting from $\partial_\mu F^{\mu \nu} = j^\nu$? In that case, I agree that an extra postulate is needed.

Comment: But if you start from QFT, you automatically know about particles, so an extra postulate isn't necessary.

Comment: @KevinZhou I tried to point out that in QFT for curved spacetime its less obvious that we even agree on what particles exist, and that in QED it is less obvious that $e$ is the charge of a (e.g. bare) positron/electron but in classical electromagnetism with particles we introduce it as a separate postulate.

Comment: And why is it a Lorentz invariant?

Comment: @marmistrz What kind of an answer are you expecting exactly? Is there some set of more fundamental principles you expect it can be derived from? Were you unsatisfied with finding out how different things would be if it weren't invariant. And fundamentally you are asking about a constant and constants depend on units and are pretty meaningless, its the dimensionless thibgs that matter. And every known particle has a charge that is equal to $\pm 3$ times the other charges or $\pm 1/3$ times the other charges or $\pm 1$ times the other charges. Those dimensionless ratio are physically meaningful.

Comment: Well, I'm simply a little overwhelmed. The only Lorentz invariants we had is the length of the time/space four vector and the energy/momentum four vector. But I still don't understand why a moving electron couldn't have a different charge, thus react differently with our "static" electrons in our frame of reference.

Comment: @marmistrz It can (and does) interact differently when moving. But if you want to **talk** about how it interacts you have to choose some language. You point out that all you had was separation (spacetime displacement) and energy-momentum, so you need more *language* and one thing you could do is call things electrons and protons and neutrons and label things in a frame independent way and then talk about how one thing acts like the other except maybe having the opposite charge so producing the opposite exchanges of momentum and energy with the fields. You could have proposed a different thing

Comment: @marmistrz I edited again.